# Overriding a Java @Nullable varargs method in Kotlin, IDE complains it overrides nothing

Tags: java, kotlin

I've got a Java method interface that looks something like this:

`@NonNull Future<List<Item>> search(@NonNull String query, @Nullable EntityType... types);`

and when I implement it in Kotlin like this (via IntelliJ implementation generation):

`override fun search(query: String, vararg roomType: EntityType?): Future<List<Item>>`

the IDE complains that it "overrides nothing". However, if the @Nullable annotation didn't exist in the Java class, there are no lint errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The annotation is labeling the *array* of varargs as nullable, not the values within the array. This seems to work:

`override fun search(query: String, roomType: Array<EntityType>?): Future<List<Item>>`

Comment: Is this an answer?